# Find a specific word in a file

Tags: perl, file, search

First, I want to search for a particular file in the directory and then in the file I need to search for a specific word. Here's what I have so far:

```
$show_bp = 'ShowBuildProcess';
$get_bs = 'GetBuildStatus';

opendir (DIR, $my_dir) or die $!;

while(my $file = readdir(DIR))
{
        if($file=~/\.log/)
        {
                if($file=~/GetBuildStatus/)
                {
```

Filenames will be like `GetStatus.<number>.log`, e.g. `GetStatus.123456.log`. I need to:

- Find all `.log` files in the directory
- Search for a file with filename starting with `GetStatus`
- Search for filename with the lower numeric part
- Search for a particular word in that file

Comment: Filenames will be like "GetStatus.123456.log" and "GetStatus.3456781.log"I need to find first all .log files in the directory and then search for a file with filename starting with GetStatus and then search for filename having lesser value that is 123456 or 3456781 and then search for a particular word in that file.

Comment: @ramki067 What do you mean "having lesser value that is 123456 or 3456781". Please, give a simple example of a log file and what do you want to get from it?

Comment: @user4035 you right. I see only `opendir` and `die`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for you: 
First we look at the file pattern and also extract `$1`,which is the first regex match )in the brackets). If the file fits we open it and look through it line by line and look for a match to your `/YourSearchPattern/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $mydir = './test/';

opendir (DIR, $mydir) or die $!;

while(my $file = readdir(DIR)){
   if ($file =~ /^GetStatus\.(\d+)\.log$/){

      if ($1 >= 123456 || $1 < 345678){
           open(my $fh,'<', $mydir . $file) or die "Cannot open file $file: $!\n";
           while (<$fh>){
             if ($_ =~ /YourSearchPattern/){
                print $_;
            }
           }
           close($fh);
      }
   }
}
```

When you look for the smallest sequence number of the files from your dir you can simply store them in an array and then sort them after those numbers:

```
...
opendir (DIR, $mydir) or die $!;

my @files;

while(my $file = readdir(DIR)){
   if ($file =~ /^GetStatus\.(\d+)\.log$/){
        push @files $file;
   }
}

my @sortedfiles = sort { my ($anum,$bnum); $a =~ /^GetStatus\.(\d+)\.log$/; $anum = $1; $b =~ /^GetStatus\.(\d+)\.log$/; $bnum = $1; $anum <=> $bnum } @files;

print $sortedfiles[0] . " has the smallest sequence number!\n";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution which is almost what i needed. However, the filenames which i mentioned is an example only. Actual filename will have different numbers which is sequential. Hence, i wanted to find the file which is having the lesser sequential number. For example: 2 files having names as "GetStatus.123456.log" and "GetStatus.123459.log"

Comment: You mean you want to find the smallest of all sequential numbers in your directory?

Comment: @ramki067 feel free to close the question/upvote when you're satisfied.